# Sublime text 3 : How to select text/contents between HTML attribute?

Tags: html, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin, emmet

I'm looking for a keyboard shortcut to select all text/contents between HTML attribute, such as:

```
<img src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/26/imagename.jpg" alt="">
```

I want to select the entire text/path in src"...." and replace for multiple images, would be much help me there any option, now I have to do everything manually.

I know, there is shortcut key something similar to "**Ctrl Shift A**" but that is select tags and text between tags, I need the same for attribute selections, eg src, href and title etc...

Please let me know if anybody know and suggestion for this type of workflow, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I'd highly recommend installing the [Expand Selection to Quotes](https://github.com/kek/sublime-expand-selection-to-quotes) SublimeText3 plugin. Simply place the cursor anywhere inside quotes (single or double), and tap **Ctrl+'** to select all text content within the quotes.

I use this all the time for use-cases like yours, and it's especially useful for multi-line cursor navigation (i.e. say you have 10 active cursors across 10 non-identical HTML lines of code, and want to jump over an entire set of bracket-holding text for all 10 cursors, without getting them out of sync).

Comment: it zooms instead :(

Comment: @chickensoup the command is "Ctrl" in combination with the apostrophe key....not the "plus" key

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there is no way to select the *just* the content of the HTML attribute with vanilla ST3.

However, you can select the content **between quotes and the quotes themselves** using <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> (OSX) or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> (Windows).

---

If you have [Emmet](https://docs.emmet.io/actions/select-item/) installed, you can use <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>period</kbd> (select next) and <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>comma</kbd> (select previous).

[Source](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/select-all-text-between-quotes-brackets/2248).

Comment: Edit:
yes, but however your technique, the Emmet shortcut almost works for me thanks, now I could select the following way that, firstly select the starting attribute of src" CTRL + D for multiple till needs and then CTRL + Shift + > it's working awesome!!, thank you so much @dam Johnson!, it's really useful!

Comment: I have Emmet. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it worked this way at the time this post was written, but <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> (Expand Selection) works fine for me on Sublime 3 (build 4113) on OSX. I tested this by copying your snippet into an HTML file and after clicking on the text in the `src` tag, I was able to select the entire path (without the quotes).